# Print line ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

When I try to use print line to see my array list, the way it's getting printed is not how I want it to be. What do I need to change to receive just the name?

This is how I am adding a new contact:

```
public class ContactGroup
{
ArrayList<Contact> contactList= new ArrayList<Contact>();

Public void addContact(String aCName)
{
Contact contact= new Contact(aCName);
contactList.add(contact);
}


public class Contact
{
private String name;

public Contact(String aCName)
{
   super();
   this.name = aCName;
}
}
```

Comment: Add a toString() method to your class containing the ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Contact> contactList= new ArrayList<Contact>();
    // code to insert contact in list
    for(Contact contact : contactList) {
        System.out.println(contact.getName());
    }
}
```

Did you try this to print name only? Another option is to override `toString()` method as:

```
public class Contact {
    private  String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Contact(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Contact{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And then use it as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Contact> contactList= new ArrayList<Contact>();
        // code to insert contact in list
        for(Contact contact : contactList) {
            System.out.println(contact);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great! Thank you:) - The print name only part worked just fine

Comment: I was just wondering if it was at all possible to add an int to my array list. The list is already declared and populated, is there anyway to add a number to each string in the array list?

Comment: The list contains objects of class `Contact` and you cannot add `int` to it.

Comment: What if the class Contact already has an int set to 0 - is there anyway to change that int value after the list has been populated?

Comment: Yes you can. You need to iterate over the list and change `int` value for each of the `Contact` object. If you have any other doubt I recommend to ask a new question :)

Comment: Cant make a new question for awhile, the int is being declared in public class Contact and is being set in the method Contact. If u can help id appreciate it but thanks so much regardless!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the toString() method in any object class

```
@Override
public String toString(){return "My Text to display";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override toString() method in your class Contact

```
public class Contact
{
private String name;

public Contact(String aCName)
{
   super();
   this.name = aCName;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
return "contact name " + this.name; //say you want to print the name property
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement toString() method inside your class containing the ArrayList. Please follow the best practices suggested in [EffectiveJava](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=Effective%20Java%20toString&source=bl&ots=yZFfRlqZV3&sig=KO1Jv4GJruvGQ0-_Od_NL8gnUyQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qupKVbaiJ5GTuATh4IGwAg&ved=0CE8Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Effective%20Java%20toString&f=false) while implementing the toString() method.

Answer (score 0):

you should add a toString() implementation to Contact class

```
public class Contact{
     private String Name;
     public Contact(String name){
          this.Name=name;
     }

    // add toString method here
    @Override
    public String toString(){
         return "This is  a Contact of :"+this.Name;
    }
}
```